# opencsv RFC4180Parser readNext is too slow when there are too many ‘\n’ in a cell

Tags: cpu, opencsv

Recently encountered slow parsing when downloading csv files, accompanied by soaring CPU and crazy young gc. and we use RFC4180Parser to parse the file, It is probably caused by too many '\n' in a cell, has anyone encountered it? how to solve？

I read the source code implementation of opencsv. It should be that the linereader judges whether it is a new line based on '\n', and each line will be parsed to slow down. Is it possible to only replace the newline symbol?